# updated version of Android Studio (Version 2022.2.1 Flamingo)

Tags: android

In updated version of Android Studio (Version 2022.2.1 Flamingo), When I run my app, name of the project is not usually show my project name on the top of my app as old version do.

below is screenshot of my problem:-
[Not displaying name of project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UgfSM.png)

I am beginner. And I don't know how to encouter this problem

Comment: Can you add some code on how you implemented that screen.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.